# How to debug an 'invalid' Kerberos ticket header

Tags: java, spring, security, kerberos

I'm trying to use the Spring Security extension for Kerberos to so I can deploy a Java web app within a Kerberos realm which takes advantage of integrated windows authentication.

I'm working from the provided Spring Security SPNEGO auth w/ form based fallback example. Everything looks to be working up to the point that the ticket from IE is received and inspected by the web app, at which point it fails to validate with the following exception:

> GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did
>   not find the right tag)

Here is the negotiate header:

> Negotiate YIGFBgYrBgEFBQKgezB5oDAwLgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCgYJKoZIgvcSAQICBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIGCisGAQQBgjcCAh6iRQRDTlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl7II4g4ADgA1AAAADQANACgAAAAGAvAjAAAAD1NIQVJFUE9JTlQtU1BTSEFSRVBPSU5ULURFVg==

In tracing the source code in Java it appears that it throws this error if it cannot find the 'tag' which turns out to be 0x60 (or a backtick) at the start of the header. If I base64 decode this using ISO-8859-1 I can see that the first character looks to be a backtick to me so I'm now stuck.

This running the latest version of Java 7 (under Java 8 I was experiencing a bug where the 'GSSContext srcName' was null - seems to be a known bug).

Any clues on something probably quite obvious that is wrong with the header or how to decode/debug it further would be great.

Comment: This might be a NTLM ticket wrapped with SPNEGO.

Comment: OK, that would match up with some information I've found on the topic. Is there any way to confirm this, and does it indicate some misconfiguration (e.g. Kerberos not properly configured, keytab incorrect etc.) ?

Comment: Inspect the ticket with Wireshark. It will decode and show you the content.

Answer (score 0):

OK - what an idiot I have been. After reading an article on how to force use of NTLM rather than Kerberos (which suggests using the IP of the server and not the SPN to access it) I realised I was always using http://localhost:8080 and not the SPN which in my case was the host name http://sharepoint-sp:8080.

It now seems to be working if I use the SPN URL. I guess I will never be able to access this outside of the Kerberos realm or using some alias of the SPN but this ties up with everything I've read on how it is supposed to work and why it is secure.

Oh well, hope this helps someone with a similar issue.